# mysql-python on mac osx 10.9.2: error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mysql-python

I wanted to port my django app from sqlite to mysql.

But when I'm trying to install mysql-python, it gives me this error:
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

I looked around for clues and tried this solution which seemed to have worked for most people:

sudo su
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
pip install MySQL-python

The complete error log is here:

```
pip install MySQL-python
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python

Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
    xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Users/deeptichopra/Desktop/Applications and Softwares/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use xcode-select to change
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-y71a30-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_py

copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

/usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64

xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Users/deeptichopra/Desktop/Applications and Softwares/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use xcode-select to change

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-y71a30-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build/MySQL-python
Storing complete log in /var/root/.pip/pip.log
```

Here is /var/root/.pip/pip.log:

```
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python

  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python

    running egg_info
    writing pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found


    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /tmp/pip-build/MySQL-python has version 1.2.5, which satisfies requirement MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python

  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python

    Running command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build//var/root/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Can you upload `/var/root/.pip/pip.log` please ? :)

Comment: I added pip.log to the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I know this is a little late to the question, but for those that come along later, I believe this is because you don't have xcode or xcode tools installed. Once you have xcode, you can install xcode tools with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: I did come along much later and this was the solution. Much appreciated!

Comment: Same for me! Very good advice.