# Can't install pygame with pip as there is an error whilst runningvsetup.py bdist_wheel for pygame

Tags: python, macos, pygame, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install pygame for Python 3 on an anaconda install.

I run `pip install pygame`, and it outputs the following:

```
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.3.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pygame
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pygame ... error
  Complete output from command //anaconda/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/s0/514rk5j90q90x4s8n48ry7wc0000gn/T/pip-build-2n_0kk3y/pygame/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /var/folders/s0/514rk5j90q90x4s8n48ry7wc0000gn/T/tmpybu68q2lpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/_camera_opencv_highgui.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/_camera_vidcapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/_dummybackend.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/_numpysndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/_numpysurfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/colordict.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/font.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/freetype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/ftfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/macosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/pkgdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/sndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/sprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/surfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/sysfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  copying lib/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/gp2x
  copying lib/gp2x/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/gp2x
  copying lib/gp2x/constants.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/gp2x
  copying lib/gp2x/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/gp2x
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/threads
  copying lib/threads/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/threads
  copying lib/threads/Py25Queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/threads
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/base_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/blit_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/bufferproxy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/camera_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/cdrom_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/cdrom_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/color_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/compat_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/cursors_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/display_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/draw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/event_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/fastevent_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/font_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/font_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/freetype_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/freetype_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/ftfont_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/ftfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/gfxdraw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/image__save_gl_surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/image_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/image_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/imageext_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/imageext_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/joystick_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/key_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/mask_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/math_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/midi_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/midi_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/mixer_music_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/mixer_music_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/mixer_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/mixer_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/mouse_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/overlay_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/pixelarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/pixelcopy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/rect_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/rwobject_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/scrap_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/scrap_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/sndarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/sndarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/sprite_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/surfarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/surfarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/surflock_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/sysfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/test_test_.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/threads_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/time_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  copying test/transform_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
  copying test/test_utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
  copying test/test_utils/arrinter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
  copying test/test_utils/async_sub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
  copying test/test_utils/buftools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
  copying test/test_utils/endian.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
  copying test/test_utils/png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
  copying test/test_utils/run_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
  copying test/test_utils/test_machinery.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
  copying test/test_utils/test_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
  copying test/run_tests__tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
  copying test/run_tests__tests/run_tests__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_5_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_6_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/no_assertions__ret_code_of_1__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/zero_tests_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
  copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
  copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
  copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
  copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
  copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
  copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/invisible_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
  copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
  copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
  copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
  copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
  copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
  copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
  copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/incomplete_todo_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
  copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
  copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/docs
  copying docs/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/docs
  copying docs/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/docs
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/aacircle.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/aliens.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/arraydemo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/blend_fill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/blit_blends.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/chimp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/eventlist.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/fastevents.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/fonty.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/freetype_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/glcube.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/headless_no_windows_needed.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/liquid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/mask.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/moveit.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/oldalien.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/overlay.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/pixelarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/playmus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/prevent_display_stretching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/scaletest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/scrap_clipboard.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/scroll.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/sound.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/sound_array_demos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/stars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/testsprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  copying examples/vgrade.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
  running build_ext
  building 'pygame.scrap' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/src
  /usr/bin/clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I//anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I//anaconda/include/python3.5m -c src/scrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/src/scrap.o
  src/scrap.c:27:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
  #include "SDL.h"
           ^
  1 error generated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pygame
  Running setup.py clean for pygame
Failed to build pygame
Installing collected packages: pygame
  Running setup.py install for pygame ... error
    Complete output from command //anaconda/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/s0/514rk5j90q90x4s8n48ry7wc0000gn/T/pip-build-2n_0kk3y/pygame/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/s0/514rk5j90q90x4s8n48ry7wc0000gn/T/pip-yhcf0tlb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/_camera_opencv_highgui.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/_camera_vidcapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/_dummybackend.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/_numpysndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/_numpysurfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/colordict.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/font.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/freetype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/ftfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/macosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/pkgdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/sndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/sprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/surfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/sysfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/gp2x
    copying lib/gp2x/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/gp2x
    copying lib/gp2x/constants.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/gp2x
    copying lib/gp2x/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/gp2x
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/threads
    copying lib/threads/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/threads
    copying lib/threads/Py25Queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/threads
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/base_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/blit_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/bufferproxy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/camera_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/cdrom_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/cdrom_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/color_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/compat_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/cursors_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/display_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/draw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/event_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/fastevent_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/font_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/font_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/freetype_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/freetype_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/ftfont_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/ftfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/gfxdraw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/image__save_gl_surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/image_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/image_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/sprite_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/surfarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/surfarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/surflock_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/sysfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/test_test_.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/threads_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/time_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/transform_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/arrinter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/async_sub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/buftools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/endian.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/run_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/test_machinery.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/test_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    copying test/run_tests__tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    copying test/run_tests__tests/run_tests__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_2_test.py -> 
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/__init__.py -> 
    copying examples/sound.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/sound_array_demos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/stars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/testsprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/vgrade.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pygame/examples
    running build_ext
    building 'pygame.scrap' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/src
    /usr/bin/clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I//anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I//anaconda/include/python3.5m -c src/scrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/src/scrap.o
    src/scrap.c:27:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
    #include "SDL.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "//anaconda/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/s0/514rk5j90q90x4s8n48ry7wc0000gn/T/pip-build-2n_0kk3y/pygame/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/s0/514rk5j90q90x4s8n48ry7wc0000gn/T/pip-yhcf0tlb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/s0/514rk5j90q90x4s8n48ry7wc0000gn/T/pip-build-2n_0kk3y/pygame/
```

Yes, it's huge! I have cut out loads of lines like `copying lib/...` to fit inside the 30,000 character limit of SE.

I have tried the following:

```
pip install pygame
pip install pygame --no-cache-dir
pip install pygame --force-reinstall
pip install pygame --no-binary :all:
pip install pygame --no-use-wheel
```

They all gave basically the same error.

I can't work out what is wrong, as this is a brand new install of anaconda.

The lines:

```
#include "SDL.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

are obviously the most important part, which implies a bug in the code. Is there an obvious error here? If it is a Python script, then it shouldn't be run, as it is commented out.

I've googled the error, and other people with a similar error like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994429/mysql-python-on-mac-osx-10-9-2-error-command-usr-bin-clang-failed-with-exit) needed to run `xcode-select --install` to solve it.

If I run that, I get this:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

So that is not my problem.

There is also the important line:

```
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pygame ... error
```

Does anyone have any insights that might help me?

Comment: The problem is in new XCode that shut down some support ( I got similar issue with wxPython ) but I managed to make `pygame` work (version 1.9.2) so try `pip install pygame==1.9.2` since it is by default trying to get 1.9.3

Comment: @JanSila Wow, thanks! Please put that as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: great, glad it hepled :)

Comment: btw if you want to accept the answer, you need to click on the tick, not the sign up :)

Comment: @JanSila I upvoted straight after the answer was posted, but it wouldn't let me accept for 10 mins, by which time I was doing something else :)

Comment: I tried that version and received this error:

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'version.py.in'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pygame installation issue in mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974339/pygame-installation-issue-in-mac-os)

Comment: I also encountered a similar problem, but my resolution was different. Turns out I needed to update pip with "pip install --upgrade pip". I was then able to install pygame.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just run this and you'll be able to work with the latest version of PyGame.
This command installs the missing dependencies that cause your error.

```
brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi
```

Then you can run `pip install pygame` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is in new XCode that shut down some support ( I got similar issue with wxPython ) but I managed to make `pygame` work (version 1.9.2) so try `pip install pygame==1.9.2` since it is by default trying to get 1.9.3

Also the `#include "SDL.h"` is C++, not python, so it is not a comment, rather it is importing a library SDL :)