# pip install pygame - SDL.h file not found

Tags: python, pygame, pip, sdl, file-not-found

MacOS Sierra

```
➜  fun_python $ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

`pip install pygame` is giving me the following error: `src/scrap.c:27:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found`, `error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1`, `#include "SDL.h"`. I don't see this SDL/SDL.h file under `/usr/include/...` folder tree.

gave me the following error.

```
➜  fun_python $ pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-1.9.3.tar.gz (3.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.0MB 490kB/s
Installing collected packages: pygame
  Running setup.py install for pygame ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/lx/smky81v534q9ydghqkjbkqv80000gp/T/pip-build-to90wzsv/pygame/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/lx/smky81v534q9ydghqkjbkqv80000gp/T/pip-jhi5wezf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/_camera_opencv_highgui.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/_camera_vidcapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/_dummybackend.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/_numpysndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/_numpysurfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/colordict.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/freetype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/ftfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/macosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/pkgdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/sndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/sprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/surfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/sysfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    copying lib/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/gp2x
    copying lib/gp2x/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/gp2x
    copying lib/gp2x/constants.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/gp2x
    copying lib/gp2x/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/gp2x
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/threads
    copying lib/threads/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/threads
    copying lib/threads/Py25Queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/threads
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/base_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/blit_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/bufferproxy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/camera_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/cdrom_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/cdrom_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/color_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/compat_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/cursors_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/display_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/draw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/event_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/fastevent_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/font_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/font_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/freetype_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/freetype_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/ftfont_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/ftfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/gfxdraw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/image__save_gl_surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/image_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/image_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/imageext_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/imageext_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/joystick_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/key_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/mask_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/math_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/midi_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/midi_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_music_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_music_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/mouse_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/overlay_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/pixelarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/pixelcopy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/rect_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/rwobject_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/scrap_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/scrap_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/sndarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/sndarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/sprite_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/surfarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/surfarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/surflock_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/sysfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/test_test_.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/threads_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/time_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    copying test/transform_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/arrinter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/async_sub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/buftools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/endian.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/run_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/test_machinery.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/test_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/test_utils
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    copying test/run_tests__tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    copying test/run_tests__tests/run_tests__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_5_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_6_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/no_assertions__ret_code_of_1__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/zero_tests_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_1_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/invisible_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/incomplete_todo_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/docs
    copying docs/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/docs
    copying docs/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/docs
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/aacircle.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/aliens.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/arraydemo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/blend_fill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/blit_blends.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/chimp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/eventlist.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/fastevents.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/fonty.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/freetype_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/glcube.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/headless_no_windows_needed.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/liquid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/mask.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/moveit.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/oldalien.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/overlay.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/pixelarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/playmus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/prevent_display_stretching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scaletest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scrap_clipboard.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scroll.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/sound.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/sound_array_demos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/stars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/testsprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    copying examples/vgrade.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pygame/examples
    running build_ext
    building 'pygame.scrap' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/src
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -c src/scrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/src/scrap.o
    src/scrap.c:27:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
    #include "SDL.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/lx/smky81v534q9ydghqkjbkqv80000gp/T/pip-build-to90wzsv/pygame/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/lx/smky81v534q9ydghqkjbkqv80000gp/T/pip-jhi5wezf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/lx/smky81v534q9ydghqkjbkqv80000gp/T/pip-build-to90wzsv/pygame/
➜  fun_python $
```

Comment: Try downlading and installing the SDL c/c++ libraries

Comment: _pygame_ (the  _C_ sources built) doesn't seem to exist for your platform (_OSX_ ) and your _Python_ version on [\[pypy\]: pypy](https://pypy.org/), so`pip` downloads the sources (_C_) and tries to build(compile) them, but it fails because it needs _SDL_, and it cant' find it. Maybe [\[Macrumors\]: Installing SDL](http://guides.macrumors.com/Installing_SDL) could help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install pygame with pip as there is an error whilst runningvsetup.py bdist\_wheel for pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806977/cant-install-pygame-with-pip-as-there-is-an-error-whilst-runningvsetup-py-bdist)

Comment: @CristiFati I agree. One of the solution in that post, helped. `brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi && pip3 install pygame && pip install pygame`

Comment: @ArunSangal your latest comment solved it for me, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pygame installation issue in mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974339/pygame-installation-issue-in-mac-os)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This helped solved the issue. Use `sudo` if necessary.

```
brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi;
pip3 install pygame;
pip install pygame
```

Answer (score 0):

After following the `brew install` answer from @AKS, it also works with `pipenv install pygame`