# Problem installing the PyGame module via pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygame

I'm trying to install the `pygame` module for Python, but I receive the following error in the traceback:

`pip install pygame`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
Juris-MacBook-Pro:~ j.alj0$ sudo pip3 install pygame
Password:
WARNING: The directory '/Users/j.alj0/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/j.alj0/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pygame
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.2MB 464kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pygame
  Running setup.py install for pygame ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-q0y248fw/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-q0y248fw/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-0t79g4wb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-q0y248fw/pygame/
    Complete output (219 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/surfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/sysfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_camera_vidcapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/sndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/draw_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/colordict.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/ftfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/font.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_numpysndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/sprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/macosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_numpysurfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/freetype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_camera_opencv_highgui.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/pkgdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_dummybackend.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
    copying src_py/threads/Py25Queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
    copying src_py/threads/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/base_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/font_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/rwobject_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/pixelcopy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/overlay_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/scrap_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/touch_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/imageext_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/pixelarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/draw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/transform_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/blit_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/bufferproxy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/surfarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mouse_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/surfarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/event_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/imageext_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/sprite_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/touch_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/gfxdraw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/rect_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/scrap_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/overlay_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/color_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/camera_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/surflock_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/key_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/sysfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/font_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/constants_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_music_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/sndarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/image_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/version_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/freetype_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/joystick_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/midi_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/ftfont_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/image__save_gl_surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/cdrom_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/cursors_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/fastevent_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/display_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/fastevent_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/compat_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/ftfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/cdrom_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mask_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/midi_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/freetype_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/math_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/time_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/image_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/threads_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_music_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/sndarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/test_test_.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/run_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/endian.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/test_machinery.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/test_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/arrinter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/buftools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/async_sub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    copying test/run_tests__tests/run_tests__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    copying test/run_tests__tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_5_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/no_assertions__ret_code_of_1__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/zero_tests_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_6_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_1_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/invisible_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/incomplete_todo_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
    copying docs/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
    copying docs/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/playmus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/mask.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/sound.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/overlay.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/aacircle.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/chimp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/liquid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/audiocapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/sound_array_demos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scroll.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/moveit.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/blit_blends.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/testsprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/textinput.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/vgrade.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/arraydemo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/stars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/blend_fill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/fonty.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/headless_no_windows_needed.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/fastevents.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/prevent_display_stretching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/glcube.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/aliens.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/freetype_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scaletest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/video.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/eventlist.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scrap_clipboard.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/oldalien.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/pixelarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/dropevent.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    running build_ext
    building 'pygame.gfxdraw' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c/SDL_gfx
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src_c/gfxdraw.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c/gfxdraw.o
    In file included from src_c/gfxdraw.c:33:
    In file included from src_c/pygame.h:32:
    src_c/_pygame.h:216:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
    #include <SDL.h>
             ^~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-q0y248fw/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-q0y248fw/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-0t79g4wb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: There's a good question buried in there, but you need to format the question for readability. Please edit your question and use the markup language appropriately. In particular, you need to use ``` to wrap blocks of code, tracebacks, command output, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992243/pip-install-pygame-sdl-h-file-not-found

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had problems with this before. You are likely having one of 2 problems:

1. Set the path of pip which will be in scripts folder of Python probably and update your environment variables.
2. At the end of your error, it lets you know you have an out of date version of pip. Updating it to the latest version fixed this problem for me.

Comment: Pretty sure the real error is that OP does not have gcc installed.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The relevant bit of your error output is

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Almost certainly, you don't have gcc (the GNU C Compiler) installed. This is frequently needed with Python modules, because many of them are *extension* modules written in C, which need to be compiled first.

I googled "pip command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1" and found links to many existing StackOverflow questions. Always google the error message!

Comment: Mmmm.. i actually did google it. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

`sudo easy_install-3.8 pygame`

As the `pygame` installs through `pip` are known to have some issues on MacOS, as discussed [here](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/466).

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked! At least I think... either way thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Could you accept the answer then so the following searchers will see this? :)