# I can't install Pygame in my Mac using pip due to two errors

Tags: python, macos, module, pygame, python-module

I'm trying to install the module Pygame in my mac, but I keep getting errors. I already have `pip` installed, so I'm not sure what is wrong. I already tried: `sudo pip install pygame`, `sudo pip3 install pygame`, and both of these without `sudo`. I would really appreciate if you could help, thanks! Here is the error message (some of the most important messages):
`error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

```
In file included from src_c/gfxdraw.c:33:
  In file included from src_c/pygame.h:32:
  src_c/_pygame.h:216:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
  #include <SDL.h>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install pygame - SDL.h file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992243/pip-install-pygame-sdl-h-file-not-found)

Comment: You may find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60144378/7774555).