# Getting pygame installed

Tags: python, pip, pygame

[Using this video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-WhAS6qzsU&feature=emb_logo), I am trying to install pygame on a Mac (I am using pip3 instead of pip).  However, I get the following error.  Any ideas?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

 command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/zr/r07m06dn4qj70kddx63gbt2w0000gn/T/pip-install-s1km657d/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/zr/r07m06dn4qj70kddx63gbt2w0000gn/T/pip-install-s1km657d/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/zr/r07m06dn4qj70kddx63gbt2w0000gn/T/pip-record-iw2de3d4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile

     cwd: /private/var/folders/zr/r07m06dn4qj70kddx63gbt2w0000gn/T/pip-install-s1km657d/pygame/

Complete output (218 lines):

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/surfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/sysfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/_camera_vidcapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/sndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/draw_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/colordict.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/ftfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/_numpysndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/sprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/macosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/_numpysurfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/freetype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/_camera_opencv_highgui.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/pkgdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

copying src_py/_dummybackend.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads

copying src_py/threads/Py25Queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads

copying src_py/threads/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/base_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/font_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/mixer_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/rwobject_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/pixelcopy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/overlay_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/scrap_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/touch_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/imageext_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/pixelarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/draw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/transform_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/blit_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/bufferproxy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/surfarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/mouse_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/surfarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/event_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/imageext_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/sprite_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/touch_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/gfxdraw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/rect_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/scrap_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/overlay_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/color_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/camera_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/surflock_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/key_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/sysfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/font_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/mixer_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/constants_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/mixer_music_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/sndarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/image_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/version_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/freetype_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/joystick_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/midi_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/ftfont_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/image__save_gl_surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/cdrom_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/cursors_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/fastevent_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/display_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/fastevent_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/compat_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/ftfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/cdrom_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/mask_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/midi_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/freetype_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/math_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/time_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/image_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/threads_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/mixer_music_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/sndarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/test_test_.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

copying test/surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils

copying test/test_utils/run_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils

copying test/test_utils/endian.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils

copying test/test_utils/test_machinery.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils

copying test/test_utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils

copying test/test_utils/png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils

copying test/test_utils/test_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils

copying test/test_utils/arrinter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils

copying test/test_utils/buftools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils

copying test/test_utils/async_sub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests

copying test/run_tests__tests/run_tests__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests

copying test/run_tests__tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok

copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok

copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok

copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok

copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok

copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_5_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok

copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/no_assertions__ret_code_of_1__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok

copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/zero_tests_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok

copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_6_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1

copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1

copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1

copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1

copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete

copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete

copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete

copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop

copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop

copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_1_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop

copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr

copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr

copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr

copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr

copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout

copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout

copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout

copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout

copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo

copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo

copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo

copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude

copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude

copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude

copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude

copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/invisible_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout

copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout

copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout

copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything

copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything

copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything

copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything

copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/incomplete_todo_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything

copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs

copying docs/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs

copying docs/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/playmus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/mask.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/sound.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/overlay.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/aacircle.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/chimp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/liquid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/audiocapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/sound_array_demos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/scroll.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/moveit.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/blit_blends.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/testsprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/textinput.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/vgrade.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/arraydemo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/stars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/blend_fill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/fonty.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/headless_no_windows_needed.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/fastevents.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/prevent_display_stretching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/glcube.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/aliens.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/freetype_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/scaletest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/video.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/eventlist.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/scrap_clipboard.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/oldalien.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/pixelarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

copying examples/dropevent.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples

running build_ext

building 'pygame.gfxdraw' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c/SDL_gfx

gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src_c/gfxdraw.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c/gfxdraw.o

In file included from src_c/gfxdraw.c:33:

In file included from src_c/pygame.h:32:

src_c/_pygame.h:216:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found

#include <SDL.h>

         ^~~~~~~

1 error generated.

---

For help with compilation see:

    https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile

To contribute to pygame development see:

    https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

---

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/zr/r07m06dn4qj70kddx63gbt2w0000gn/T/pip-install-s1km657d/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/zr/r07m06dn4qj70kddx63gbt2w0000gn/T/pip-install-s1km657d/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/zr/r07m06dn4qj70kddx63gbt2w0000gn/T/pip-record-iw2de3d4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Try using a different pygame version. Try `pip install pygame==1.9.2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install pygame with pip as there is an error whilst runningvsetup.py bdist\_wheel for pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806977/cant-install-pygame-with-pip-as-there-is-an-error-whilst-runningvsetup-py-bdist)